# Notice: Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$ticket in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\register.php on line 13

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp, database-connection

I tried to create a simple registration page using php, mongodb as database in Xampp.
But it is showing the following error.

```
Notice: Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$ticket in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\register.php on line 13

Notice: Trying to get property 'login' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\register.php on line 14

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function insert() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\register.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\register.php on line 16
```

I have not been able to fix the error, please help me to solve if you can.

**PHP version:- 7.2.1
mongodb version:- 3.6.2**

registration page html file:-

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration
</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><b>Registration</b></center>
<form  method="post" action="register.php">
<input type="text" name="user_name" />
<input type="password" name="user_pass" />
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

php file:-

```
<?php

if(($_POST["user_name"])&&($_POST["user_pass"]))
{
$uname=$_POST["user_name"];
$upass=$_POST["user_pass"];
$pass=md5($upass);

$con=new MongoDB/Driver/Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
if($con)
{
$db=$con->ticket;
$collection=$db->login;
$val=array("username=>$uname","userpassword=>$pass");
$collection->insert($val);
}
else
{
die("MongoDB is not ");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You're not going LIVE with MD5?

Comment: ok,the connection is established between the data is not stored in mongodb

Comment: what you have if you do var_dump($db) ?
$collection is null, and then you cannot do $collection->insert

Comment: yes NULL #gjord83

Comment: Wht you do $db=$con->ticket ? What does it means?
Please verify also $con if is null (I think no, but better to check)

Comment: i'm getting the same error